# How to avoid duplicate rows when inserting from one table to another with Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, sql-insert

I have two tables with the following structure :

TABLE_A

```
id_a|name_a|identifier_a
1   |toto  |uuuu
2   |titi  |oooo
3   |tutu  |vvvv
```

TABLE_B

```
id_b|name_b|identifier_b
1   |toto  |uuuu
11  |tyty  |tttt
56  |tetu  |bbbb
```

I'm trying to insert data from TABLE_B to TABLE_B without duplicate lines by using the identifier column. So, the expected result should be :

```
id_a|name_a|identifier_a
1   |toto  |uuuu
2   |titi  |oooo
3   |tutu  |vvvv
11  |tyty  |tttt
56  |tetu  |bbbb
```

The following request to do this is :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A(ID_A, NAME_A, IDENTIFIER_A)
SELECT ID_B, NAME_B, IDENTIFIER_B 
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT IDENTIFIER_A FROM TABLE_A);
```

But I get an error saying that a column is not valid (???) :

```
SQL Error : ORA-00904: "IDENTIFIER_B" : 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Have you have better ideas to do this insert ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `MERGE` statement for this purpose - to insert only rows that doesn't exists in the target table.

Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) - the MERGE statement can also update the existing rows

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_B b
USING TABLE_A a
ON (a.id_a = b.id_b)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id_b, name_b, identifier_b)
  VALUES (id_a, name_a, identifier_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear enough: there is no column called `identifier_b` in table `b`. You need to use the proper column name.

Let me pinpoint, however, that your query does not do what you want: you need to correlated the `EXISTS` subquery, otherwise no rows will ever get inserted (unless `table_a` is empty to start with).

I think the logic you want is:

```
insert into table_a(id_a, name_a, identifier_a)
select id_b, name_b, identifier_b 
from table_b b
where not exists (select 1 from table_a a where a.identifier_a = b.identifier_b);
```